# Deleting an item in tableView removes the wrong corresponding file from stored values (swift NSCoding)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I used the code below to delete an item from a TableView and the corresponding file from the archive. If I delete the 4th item of the TableView, it deletes the 4th file of the stored values. As the TableView is dynamic(sorting items or changing the number of items that it displays)and the archive is stable, the code deletes the wrong files, as the 1st item in the view could be the 6th in the stored Files. So when the view is reloaded an item is deleted but not the one I wanted. (I used NSCoding to store values). Every item has a unique id and every file a unique name(which is the id), but  I can only retrieve the id of the truly deleted item and not the one I swipe to delete. Could you please help me? Thank you.

```
self.tableOfExpences.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        
//REMOVING FROM THE STORED VALUES================         
        
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
 let paths:[String] = Bundle.paths(forResourcesOfType: "dat", inDirectory: documentsPath)
        if paths.count > 0 {
             do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: paths[indexPath.row])
                print("deleted File has been removed")
                } catch {
                print("an error during a removing")
                }
        }
        
   
                
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
```

Trying to solve possible sync problem

First, I make sure the table view knows what it shows. And it appears the arrays are synced.
In the debug area I read:

> the first cell is the Optional("**Chocolate**") and has the ID Optional(**6**)
>
> the second cell is the Optional("**phone**") and has the ID Optional(**7**)

The above are correct.

Then I swipe to remove the second cell (the phone) with **ID 7** and it informs me that a totally different expense with another ID and another path will be removed.

For the above problem the solution came with [indexPath.row-1] instead of [indexPath.row].

```
     if indexPath.row == 0 {
            
            self.tableOfExpences.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            
        } else {
        self.tableOfExpences.remove(at: indexPath.row-1)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
```

The above solution worked but when I deleted the last item the app crashed. So after watching similar Questions the solution was to go back to [indexPath.row] instead of [indexPath.row-1] and just reverse the order of lines so that first to delete data from the file

```
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: paths[indexPath.row])
```

and then to implement the

```
   self.tableOfExpences.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

I hope that the above will help someone with similar problems.Of course without the filePth property and the sync debuging I would still watch the code crash.Thank you for the great help. It was a wonderfull week.

Comment: Your row in the table need to be some kind of struct or class instance and that instance needs to hold the path to the file.

Comment: You need to associate a unique value (for example the file name) to the item in the table view. Then you can identify the file by name.

Comment: Yes, every row has the Expense class, which holds, among others, a unique ID but not a path to the file. I 'm new to coding and I understood the problem quite late. It seems that the code recognizes only the position of the item in the ever changing TableView and not its id. Could you please please propose any book or similar cases code? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Expense model to have a path property. When you create an Expense and store it to the file system, store the path of that Expense, and use it later when you want to delete the expense

```
struct Expense {
    let filePath: String
    // .... other properties
}
```

Then you can just call:

```
try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: expenses[indexPath.row].filePath)
```

Comment: I don't have much experience, so my design was quite poor.Thank you very much Marmoy. I 'll try the array of tuples.

Comment: Thank you Marmoy. I added the filePath property on my OneExpence Class and now the array of the stored values agrees with the view(which is perfect) but the files don't delete(I swipe to delete and when the view reloads they are there. Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: use breakpoints to check whether the right code gets executed when you swipe to delete, and also, ensure that the call to  FileManager.default.removeItem atPath succeeds. If it does not, investigate the error that is thrown to understand why.

Comment: I notice that when I print the path it misses the last part( /filename.dat) although I included it.
        let fileName = (e.nextID)!.description + ".dat"
        let fullPath = pathToSave + "/" + fileName

Comment: I changed the structure of the code and it now works deleting the file  with the line you gave me .So one great problem is solved. Thank you. Then I found out that I have also a sync problem with the view and the source as Scriptable said.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely being caused by your two arrays getting out of sync.

When you get the paths array by fetching the documents in the Documents directory you have no guarantee that they will be returned in teh same sorted order that your table data is.

You could also add the path to the expenses model instead, which would be much more reliable

Comment: the first cell is the Optional("Chocolate") and has the ID Optional(6)
the second cell is the Optional("phone") and has the ID Optional(7)

Comment: First I make sure the TableView knows what it shows. And it appears the arrays are synced. 
DebugArea:

the first cell is the Optional("Chocolate") and has the ID Optional(6)
the second cell is the Optional("phone") and has the ID Optional(7)

Comment: Then I swipe to remove  the second cell(the phone) and it informs me that a totaly different Expense with another ID and another path   (the console in 
DebugArea):

The removed from the table expense is the Optional(4)
We had bought a Optional("party1")
The name of the file to be deleted is 4.dat
The name of the path with the file to be deleted is Optional("/Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AE26EA55-FCF5-4196-A2E8-D025D37BF01F/data/Containers/Data/Application/C81BF30A-8A2B-4F2D-B93B-74D406FDECC6/Documents/4.dat")

Comment: Any idea how can such a thing happen? My simple code:

if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            self.tableOfExpences.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

Comment: After debugging for the new problem the solution came with [indexPath.row-1] instead of [indexPath.row]. Thank you for the guidance Scriptable.

Comment: I have been on holiday so not been able to reply. Glad you worked it out

Comment: If  you had not told me about sync, I would still be searching. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the paths, just like the items in the table are sorted.

```
Bundle.paths(forResourcesOfType: "dat", inDirectory: documentsPath).a.sorted { $0 < $1 } // your logic sorting
```