# swift: Table View Deletes wrong file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to delete an item from a table view.

- First I added a filePath property on my class (that was missing)
- Then I corrected the line of code to find the right filePath

the problem is solved but still I have the wrong file deleted so I check the sync of the arrays.

First, I make sure the table view knows what it shows and it appears the arrays are synced. I debug the code and I find that when I swipe to delete an item the code still deletes another file.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableOfExpences.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellOfExpencesTableViewCell

    let myOneExpense = self.tableOfExpences[indexPath.row]


    if myOneExpense.size != nil  {


        //Arrangement Of the cell


        //allocate the right image for each segment



    } else {
        cell.nameCellLabel?.text = "No Cost"
    }

    return cell
}


 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        self.tableOfExpences.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        print("the removed from the table expence is the \(String(describing: tableOfExpences[indexPath.row].expenseID))")
        print("We had bought a \(String(describing: tableOfExpences[indexPath.row].note))")
```

In my case there was a numerous things why the wrong file was deleted but the most tricky(when all the code seemed to be correct) was that first the file must be removed from the directory and then the cell from the table.

So just reversing the order of lines so that first to delete data from the file

```
try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: paths[indexPath.row])
```

and then to implement the

```
 self.tableOfExpences.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

solved the last great problem.

Comment: Sorry but your question is lacking a lot of necessary details to provide help. Please update your question to show your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods. Show your `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting an item in tableView removes the wrong corresponding file from stored values (swift NSCoding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023278/deleting-an-item-in-tableview-removes-the-wrong-corresponding-file-from-stored-v)

Comment: The question above solved the problem of finding the stored file as 1.a filePath property was added and 2. the correct line of code for that filePath was recommended.

Comment: For better future reference I added this question as a part  of the [Deleting an item in tableView removes the wrong corresponding file from stored values (swift NSCoding)] where is made clear how to remove the file following the filePath.

Comment: Once again (as suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023278/deleting-an-item-in-tableview-removes-the-wrong-corresponding-file-from-stored-v)) add a property `filePath` (or better `fileURL`) to you `tableOfExpences` model and assign the path / URL of the corresponding file. Then just get the path / URL and delete the file.

Comment: Thank you vadian. The new problem described here appeared once I add the filePath and implemented the code as suggested(which solved the real problem). After debugging for the new problem the solution came with  [indexPath.row-1] instead of [indexPath.row] (sorry, I'm new to code).